# A better way to write if..else block in typescript with network call in between

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I find myself writing a lot of code like this;

```
if(cond){
   /*do some network call */
   this.networkService.invoke(params).subscribe((res) => {
      this.doSomething();
   })
}else{
   /* do something without calling the network */
   this.doSomething();
}
```

Essentially, `this.doSomething();` has to be called whether the condition is met or not. If the `cond === true`, then do some network call, then `this.doSomething()`. Is there a better way to write such code?

Comment: I guess that's an observable, and I don't really have experience with those, but with a *promise* the pattern would look something like: `const p = cond ? this.nS.invoke() : Promise.resolve(); p.then(() => this.doSomething());`. In other words, construct a promise either way, then resolve `doSomething` asynchronously either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By converting your observable to promise and making the parent function async, you can do this:

```js
async parentFunction() {
    ...
    cond && await this.networkService.invoke(params).toPromise()
    this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much the answer, but i would recommend just using an `if` statement rather than abusing `&&` weirdness.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I agree. using the `if` statement makes the code more readable and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't what you're asking, but most of the time (IMHO) the problem with this type of code is that it's sometimes synchronous and sometimes asynchronous. To avoid this you can use the `rxjs` operator `of` to always go the async way.

I did something similar recently with a cache service. The idea here is to always return an `Observable` even if the data is already loaded;

```
private data: SomeData[] = null;
private isLoadedOrOnItsWay = false;
private subject: Subject<SomeData[]> = new Subject<SomeData[]>();

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

public getAll(): Observable<SomeData[]> {
    if (!this.isLoadedOrOnItsWay) {
        this.isLoadedOrOnItsWay = true;
        this.dataService.getData<SomeData[]>().subscribe(x => {
            // Load from service...
            this.data = x;
            this.subject.next(x);
        });
    } else if (this.data) {
        // Get from cache
        return of(this.data);
    }

    // Return subject and wait for data to be loaded
    return this.subject;
}
```